# I'm using v2.71 and I can't find any blend sky option under the world tab

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm using v2.71 and I can't find any blend sky option under the world tab. I'm following a tutorial that used an older version of Blender.Where is it in the newest version, or how do I set the Horizon and Zenith colors?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your using **blender internal**.

[image]

It's under the world panel as per screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Set your render engine to **Blender Render**

[image]

Then go to Properties->World tab,
enable **Blend Sky** and assign the colors you want for Horizon and Zenith.

[image]